# Question on proof of when you add two rows on a matrix, why does $\det(B) = \det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> Applying to a square matrix $A$ the row operation $R_i + \alpha R_j$ (that is, adding to Row $i$ a multiple of Row $j$), we obtain a new matrix $B$. Prove that $\det(B) = \det(A)$.

This is the proof:

$$\det(B) = \det \pmatrix{ a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{i1} + \alpha a_{j1} & \cdots & a_{in} + \alpha a_{jn} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots &a_{nn}}$$

$$ = \det \underbrace{ \pmatrix{ a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{in}  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots &a_{nn}} }_{\text{ A}} + \det \pmatrix{ a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \alpha a_{j1} & \cdots & \alpha a_{jn} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots &a_{nn}}$$

$$ = \det(A) + \alpha \det \underbrace{ \pmatrix{ a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{j1} & \cdots &  a_{jn} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots &a_{nn}}}_{\text{= 0 as two identical rows}}$$

$$= \det(A).$$

The bit I don't get is when you split $B$ up, how do you get that second matrix on the right? Shouldn't that have all zeros excepts for on row $i$ otherwise when you add it up, you will get double values on every entrance except for row $i$ wouldn't you?

Comment: The determinant is "column-wise" and "row-wise" linear, don't forget that.

Comment: Think about the matrix you need to multiply by to achieve the effect of adding one row to another, and look at the determinant of that. Not exactly what the question asks, but equivalent.

Comment: The matrix in the determinant on the first line is not being "split up" as a sum of two matrices on the second line.  There is no general rule for the determinant of a sum of two matrices, so another approach is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant is "column-wise" and "row-wise" linear, don't forget that. Thus, you have on one row that $$\begin{align}\det(R_1\mid \cdots \mid R_i+\alpha R_j\mid \cdots \mid R_b)= &\det(R_1\mid \cdots \mid R_i\mid \cdots \mid R_n)\\&+\;\alpha \det(R_1\mid \cdots \mid R_j\mid \cdots \mid R_n)\end{align}$$

That is, if we fix all the other $n-1$ rows, or $n-1$ columns, the determinant behaves exactly like a linear transformation on the "row vectors" or "column vectors". We also use that it is alternate, so equal rows yield a null image.

Comment: @amWhy Nope. I was about to tell you to look at $$\begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ though.

Comment: Because the statement you made about the determinant of a sum is not true in general.

Comment: I don't see why *I* was downvoted, since what I'm saying is true. The determinant is a multilinear alternating form.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff What do you mean by columnwise and rowwise linear?

Comment: @Kaish "That is, if we fix..." Did you read what I wrote?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff When you say fix, you just mean like leave it and don't alter it any way yeah?

Comment: @amWhy First off, I wasn't the downvoter.  I _was_ in the midst of posting my comment when your answer was deleted.

Comment: @Kaish Yes, when I say "fix" I mean "keep it constant".

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thanks. Got it. Do you know about my other matrix questions?

Comment: @Kaish It might be worth noting that this is one of the defining properties of the determinant. You're notes should probably state it. Of course, we should first prove there exists a multilienar alternating form, (and that it is unique up to the value it takes on the identity) so maybe you wanna re-read your notes.

Comment: @Peter There are several standard definitions, and not all of them use this as a defining feature. For some, it's a consequence. Just sayin'.

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes. Duly noted. It seems the OP's notes define it this way, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use [Laplace's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix).

$$det(B) = \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j} (a_{ij}+\alpha a_{kj})M_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}M_{ij} + \alpha  \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j} a_{kj}M_{ij} = det(A) + \alpha  \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j} a_{kj}M_{ij} $$

$$\alpha  \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j} a_{kj}M_{ij} = \alpha \det  \pmatrix{ a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{j1} & \cdots &  a_{jn} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots &a_{nn}}=0$$